# android: attaching file to mail

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

i have this code for sending mail:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"MyMail@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(BladeActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

how to attach to this mail the file: `/sdcard/MyFile.csv`

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/MyFile.csv"));
```

And make sure you have required permissions to access external storage.

Comment: Never use fixed path `/sdcard/`, because For example my SD-card path is `/mnt/sdcard`

Comment: @PareshMayani That's what OP asked: *how to attach to this mail the file: /sdcard/MyFile.csv*. But I agree with you generally; using `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is safer.

Comment: is there any way to sent the mail without showing the mail interface ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `javamail-android` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to attach file in mail...  This code work when i am trying to send mail..

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of Email");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/MyFile.csv"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the mail");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

Add following permission in manifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Never use fixed path `/sdcard/`, because For example my SD-card path is `/mnt/sdcard`

Answer (score 1):

use this code..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+arr));
intent.setType("image/jpg"); 
startActivity(intent);
```